Resort from descending to ascending
I have a large two part macro.
The first part vlookups data into a "master" sheet and sorts by the vlookup column so any #N/As are on top.
The idea to manually correct any #N/As from the previous Vlookup.
The second part is supposed to resort the entire sheet (columns A-W) by column B.
Previously it was descending so the #N/As would be on top and now I would like it ascending.
Everything works except the second sort.
The original sort used a one line code:
Worksheets("MASTER").Range("A1" & lastrow).Sort Key1:=Range("B1"), Order1:=xldescending, Header:=xlYes

The funny thing is, I have not set lastrow. This was a typo originally, but it works whereas what I actually set, lastrowm does not. lastrowm was set up like this:
Dim lastrowm As Long
lastrowm = Worksheets("MASTER").UsedRange.Rows.Count
If lastrowm = 1 Then
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("MASTER").UsedRange) = 0 Then lastrowm = 0
End If

I tried the code above without the If statements as well.
I'm not sure if this previous code is somehow "breaking" the file.
I added .SortFields.Clear before the second sort, but it did not help.
Here is the last code I tried for the second sort:
Dim lrow As Long
Dim lcol As Long
lrow = WS.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lcol = WS.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

WS.Cells.AutoFilter
WS.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
WS.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B1:B" & lrow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With WS.AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
WS.AutoFilterMode = False


I cannot understand what range do you try sorting... Only  "B:B" column? If so, is it separated by other columns on the sheet? In your last code you use ws sheet but you do not set it. Then, you use key:= of the active sheet. Are they the same?

Yes, I want it to sort the entire sheet (columns A-W) by column B. Sorry, I did set WS apparently just forgot to copy that part. It is set as: Dim WS As Worksheet Set WS = Sheets("MASTER"). The active sheet at the time of running the macro would not be the same as the master. Would that be the error?

Please, try the next code. It uses the necessary columns as range, sorting on "B:B" column (2):
Sub sortAWRange()
 With ActiveWorkbook
    With .Worksheets("MASTER")
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Columns("A:W")
            .cells.Sort key1:=.Columns(2), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, header:=xlYes
        End With
    End With
 End With
End Sub

Please, send some feedback after testing it.
